# What are the nuances between using "odd," "weird," or "strange" here?

Tags: meaning, usage, pronouns

Question 1:
What are the nuances between using odd, weird, or strange here?

Question2:
Is my example correct?

Example:

> A: Did you win the lottery

> B: I won the jackpot. My family does not believe I won. I have not told my other friends about this. You are my first friend to know about this.

> A: **That** sounds odd/weird/strange. Maybe it is hiding something.

By the way, "That" refers to the whole thing B is saying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- "Weird" is rather negative.
- "Strange" is still negative, but less    than "weird".
- "Odd" is not as strong: it is more "normal" than    something
  "strange" or "weird". You can see something is not normal,    but it
  is not shocking.

I offer you the following correction:

A: Did you win the lottery?

B: I won the jackpot. My family **does** not believe I won. I have not **told** my other friends about this. You are my first friend to know **about** this.

A: That sounds **strange** *(but this choice is subjective)*. Maybe **it** *(depends on what you meant?)* is hiding something.

Comment: I've noticed that posters on this site often use _weird_ to mean _strange, unusual_. However, its original meaning was 'strange in a sinister, spooky way' - Oxford dictionaries says 'suggesting something supernatural; unearthly'..

Comment: @benice So, using odd doesn't make the speaker sound judgemental, right. By the way, what does the "it" mean in your answer? Does the "it" refer to "that", which represents things B is saying.

Comment: @benice Sorry if you are busy with things. Would you mind answering my question in the comment?

Comment: @vincentlin this is a good question: I didn't know what/who is hiding something, with no other context
If this is what B is saying, it cannot be "he" or "she"
"he"/"she" are only used for people, sometimes also for animals or in some cases of anthropomorphism